Image not showing due to white space in folder and file name in Opencart
In Opencart 3.8
I have more than 30 folders and 2000 files which have white spaces in many folders and file names. Now it is not possible to edit all of them.
So I need your help on how I can change the coding to show the all images.
For ex. catalog/dia da mãe/Borboleta 1.jpg

Here is a twist: When running on a local server, the white spaces are converted to %20 and the images are displayed, but this is not happening on the server.
I am trying to covert white spaces with %20 but not showing.
$image_new = str_replace(' ', '%20', $image_new);

Please help me.

"When running on a local server, the white spaces are converted to %20" - are you talking about the actual URLs how they appear in the HTML source code here?

Are you sure the issue is due to space characters - and not perhaps rather due to "special characters" such as ã in the folder or file names? Unencoded spaces are usually encoded properly by any browser; but with characters outside of the basic ASCII range, things like charset/character encoding might come into play, when you leave URL encoding up to the client.

@C3roe catalog/dia%20da%20mãe/Astrm-200x200.jpg please check the link in my local server

And is it the same, or different, on your live system?

@C3roe different in live system
